# Unable to calculate fibonnaci numbers using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math

import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(8000000)


f = {1:2,2:3,3:5}

def fib(n):

    if n in f:
        return f[n]
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    if n == 2:
        return 3
    if n == 3:
        return 5
    val = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    if n not in f:
        f[n] = val
    return f[n]%1000000007

print(fib(4000))
```

This code fails to complete / command prompt crashes. How can I make this better?

Is there any setting that I need to enable to make this program complete?

Comment: try with some small number and print the value? It could be causing infinite loop.

Comment: it works until 3226.

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: no, the command prompt crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the Fibonacci sequence directly from the mathematical definition is an exercise that illustrates problems with recursive solutions. It leads to an exponential explosion of recursive function calls that even modern computers cannot handle. The biggest problem is that for large values of `n`, you will calculate `fib(1)` an exponential number of times.

There are several solutions to this problem:

1. Use memoization to store values that have already been calculated. Then you look up the calculated value and return it immediately without doing any further calculations. This is a good exercise to learn how memoization works. However, it is still inefficient because you still unnecessarily execute recursive function calls.
2. Implement an iterative solution. I'm not going to get into the details here. I suggest you do some research to find the iterative solution that will implement `fib(n)` in linear time instead of exponential time.
3. Implement the closed formula. Mathematicians have already solved `fib(n)` as a closed formula. This solution will take constant time no matter how large of an `n` you use.

Answer (score 0):

use automatic memorization of old vales so that it won't go into infinity loop.use lru_cache as a decorator on your function.

```
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

sys.setrecursionlimit(8000000)


f = {1:2,2:3,3:5}

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):

    if n in f:
        return f[n]
    if n == 1:
        return 2
    if n == 2:
        return 3
    if n == 3:
        return 5
    val = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    if n not in f:
        f[n] = val
    return f[n]%1000000007
print(fib(4000))
```